# Batch download bibtex data?

Tags: bibtex, google-scholar

Is there a way to batch download the bibtex data from Google Scholar or somewhere esle?

I tried a few GS Scrapers, e.g., 
https://github.com/gimoya/theBioBucket-Archives/blob/master/R/Functions/GScholarScraper_3.1.R

But none of them can download the bibtex files. A mysterious **scisig** key is need to fetch the file.

I also tried Jabref. It can get the bibtex files in bulk.
But the advanced search features in GS are all disabled.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 4):

I updated scholar.py with this functionality. See http://www.github.com/hildensia/scholar

```
$ ./scholar.py "Alan Turing Entscheidungsproblem" --bibtex --count 1

@article{turing1936computable,
  title={On computable numbers, with an application to the Entscheidungsproblem},
  author={Turing, Alan M},
  journal={Proceedings of the London mathematical society},
  volume={42},
  number={2},
  pages={230--265},
  year={1936},
  publisher={London, UK}
}

$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mendely for batch download of bibtex provided that you maintain a repository of papers using this software